# How to fix 'undefined variable: title' in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to include data from two different tables in MySQL onto one view using Laravel. The 'questions' data shows but the 'questionnaire' data does not, hence the "undefined variable: title". I have tried looking online for ages but none of the solutions seem to solve my problem.

I've already tried loading them in the same view but I am not sure if I am doing it correctly as I am extremely new to Laravel!

index.blade.php file:

```php
@foreach($question as $questionnaire)
        <h4>{{ $questionnaire->title }}</h4>
    @endforeach
```

QuestionsController file:

```php
public function index()
    {
      $question = questions::all();
      $questionnaire = questionnaires::all();
      return view('question.index',compact('question', 'questionnaire'));
    }
```

The title of the questionnaire should appear on the index page along with the questions. The questions feature works as expected so nothing needs to be touched on that part.

Any help/support would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: <h4>{{ $questionnaire->title??'' }}</h4> use ternary operator.Also can you dd($question->toArray()) and dd($questionnaire->toArray()); and post in ur question

Comment: Maybe `title` attribute is `nullable` and is null for certain `questionnaire`? You didn't show nor your model neither database schema or migration at least

Comment: @iCoders null coalesce*

Answer (score 0):

What you have now is loop through the questions collection and print out each question title:

```
@foreach($question as $questionnaire) //questionnaire here is a single question from your $questions collection
    <h4>{{ $questionnaire->title }}</h4>
@endforeach
```

You have another collection of `questionnaire` and you are not looping over it, in order to print out its values. So what you need is the following:

```
@foreach($questionnaire as $item)
    <h4>{{ $item->title }}</h4>
@endforeach
```

Your variables are confusing that's why you think you should print out both collections but you are using only one. If there is a relationship between a `question` and a `questionnaire` then that's a completely different ball-game, and you will need to provide more details for that.

Also I believe that the undefined variable errors comes from another place where you are trying to use `$title` but you are not providing it to the view.

-- EDIT

As you said, your questionnaire has many questions, you can do the following:

in your questionnaires model class:

```
public function questions() 
{
   return $this->hasMany(questions::class);
}
```

In your controller:

```
$questionnaires = questionnaires::with('questions')->get();
```

in the view:

```
@foreach($questionnaires as $questionnaire)
    <h4>{{ $questionnaire->title }}</h4>

    @foreach($questionnaire->questions as $question)
       -- <h4>{{ $question->title }}</h4>
    @endforeach

@endforeach
```

Comment: That's great thank you!! How do I get it underneath each block of questions? At the minute, the three different titles are all under one another, there needs to be data between them. Would be much appreciated!

Comment: @strong-highway do you have a relationship setup between a question and questionnaire ? For example one Question has many questionnaires?

Comment: Yes, it's one questionnaire has many questions. So each question should be associated with that questionnaire's ID but not got round to that yet - too complex!

Comment: @strong-highway look at my edited code now, this should give you an idea on how to do it.

Comment: Thank you but this doesn't seem to work for me. I'm getting an error saying that a column is not found. I'm not entirely sure what to do, like I said I have very little experience in this unfortunately

Comment: You can read the docs for one to many relationship, I don't have your code nor do I know what errors you get in order to help you. Sorry.